# C: send/recv partial packet at first connection and receives the rest at second connection

Tags: c, network-programming

Code for **client**:

```
/* Packet struct */
struct
{
    int x;
    int y;
    char mess [5];
} Packet;

/* Assigning values to packet */
Packet.x = 5;
Packet.y = 25;
strcpy(Packet.mess, "Hell");

/* Send packet */
int bytesTransmitted = send(socketID, &Packet, sizeof(Packet), 0);

/* Check transmission */
if (bytesTransmitted < 0)
{
    printf("Error sending message!\n");
    return 1;
}
else
{
    printf("Message sent successfully! Message size: %lu, bytes trasnmitted: %d", sizeof(message), bytesTransmitted);
}

/* End of pogram */
return 0;
```

Code for **server**:

```
struct
{
    int x;
    int y;
    char mess [5];
} Packet;


unsigned int clientLength = sizeof(clientAddress);

/* Main loop */
while (1)
{

    int listenSocket = accept(socketID, (struct sockaddr*)&clientAddress, &clientLength);

    if (listenSocket > 0) /* Connection accepted */
    {
        printf("Received connection from: %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(clientAddress.sin_addr), ntohs(clientAddress.sin_port));
        if (recv(listenSocket, &Packet, sizeof(Packet), 0) > 0)
        {
            printf("Message: %s\n x:%d\n y:%d", Packet.mess, Packet.x, Packet.y);
            /* HERE IS THE PROBLEM */
        }

    }
}
```

Output from server at first connection:

```
Received connection from: 127.0.0.1:48648
Message: Hell
x:5
```

*y* is missing.

I terminate the client and restart it without touching the server.

Output from server:

```
 y:25 <-- *y* from ?previous? connection

 Received connection from: 127.0.0.1:49368
 Message: Hell
 x:5 <-- *x* from current connection
```

*y* is missing again.

Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue has nothing to do with TCP streaming (though you do have that problem and should fix it per Greg's answer).

Instead, your issue is output buffering -- by default stdout is line buffered, which means that characters written with `printf` actually go into a buffer and are only output to the screen when a `\n` (newline) is written to the buffer.  So your line:

```
printf("Message: %s\n x:%d\n y:%d", ...
```

Will only print up to the last newline (before y), and the `y:25` will just be put in the buffer.  Later, when you print more stuff that includes a newline, the buffered string will appear along with whatever else you printed.  Add a newline after the "y:%d" and it will appear when you expect.

Answer (score 2):

TCP is a *stream* oriented protocol. There are no "packets" at the level you are writing code. TCP guarantees that the same bytes you send, will arrive at the destination in the same order. However, there are no message boundaries.

Your code that calls `recv()` must be prepared to receive fewer bytes than requested, and call `recv()` again until you get the number of bytes you expect.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems:

1. your server code doesn't have a newline at the end of the second printf, so the output can't be what you show. Either append a newline to that second printf, or use `fflush(stdout)` after it, to flush the value of `y`.
2. as Greg says, you can't rely on receiving entire messages anyway, and should have a loop here.

I'd expect #1 to be your current problem, but you should fix both.